# Not a "Group By" expression

Tags: oracle

I'm facing `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression 00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"` when I try to run this script in oracle

```
      SELECT m.working_minutes as minutes, sum(at.length_in_minutes)
  FROM medic m 
  inner join appointment a on a.medic_id = m.id
  inner join appointment_type at on at.id = a.appointment_type_id
  group by m.id
  HAVING TO_DATE(a.appointmet_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

but when I remove the `group by m.id` and then run the script as

```
      SELECT m.working_minutes as minutes, sum(at.length_in_minutes)
  FROM medic m 
  inner join appointment a on a.medic_id = m.id
  inner join appointment_type at on at.id = a.appointment_type_id
```

it gives me this error:

```
    ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
    00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
```

so, I don't know what to do

Comment: The error messages make sense. But what did you want to achieve here? Can you provide sample input for the involved tables and corresponding output you would expect from it?

Comment: I'm trying to get the worked minutes by a Medic in a date and the minutes that this medic is able to work in a date:                                              
 `minutes (minutes able to work) - 480 | sum - 120`

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample input for each of the involved tables, and the expected output for that sample.

Comment: Try `group by m.working_minutes` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to include the columns you are not aggregating by in the `GROUP BY` clause and your `HAVING` clause should be a `WHERE` clause that is applied before the aggregation.

```sql
SELECT m.working_minutes as minutes,
       sum(at.length_in_minutes)
FROM   medic m 
       INNER JOIN appointment a on a.medic_id = m.id
       INNER JOIN appointment_type at on at.id = a.appointment_type_id
WHERE  a.appointmet_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND    a.appointmet_date <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
GROUP BY
       -- m.id,
       m.working_minutes;
```

Also, never use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a `DATE`.

---

It sounds from your description that what you might want is:

```sql
SELECT m.id,
       MAX(m.working_minutes) as minutes,
       COALESCE(SUM(at.length_in_minutes), 0) AS time_worked
FROM   medic m 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN appointment a
       ON (   a.medic_id = m.id
          AND a.appointmet_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
          AND a.appointmet_date <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN appointment_type at
       ON (at.id = a.appointment_type_id)
GROUP BY
       m.id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b868ef6b164a6e7b3c3ddb88195ebf89)*